# Angular JS ng-model-options not working on inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

Hi I'm struggling with this code. I'm pretty sure everything is ok, but obviously it isn't. This is just some simple form validation, here's a sample input field:

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-controller="signupFormCtrl">

<!-- USERNAME -->
    <!-- USERNAME FIELD -->
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="user.name"
        name="username" 
        placeholder="Nome" 
        ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
        required />

    <!-- USERNAME ERROR -->
    <span class="error-message" 
        ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required">Ci serve il tuo nome</span>
</form>
```

Each field has one or more error messages enclosed in spans, which get shown when proper ng-show checks evaluate to true. This works fine but I want the errors to be displayed "on blur" or after a small delay.
ng-model-options i tried:

```
{ updateOn : 'blur' }, 
{ debounce : '1000' }, 
{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0}}
```

None of these options work, the error gets displayed but without any delay and ignoring the 'blur' option.

Also here's the (pretty simple) controller I'm using, could it be something in there? As far as I can tell no.

```
app.controller('signupFormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.sendInfo = function (user) {
    var userData = 'user=' + user.name + '&mail=' + user.mail + '&pwd=' + user.password;            
    }

    //AJAX CALL TO SERVER-SIDE LOGIC
}]);
```

Thanks in advance for those willing to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I have to ask the question : which version of angular are you using ? ( ngModelOptions is an angular 1.3 feature )

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm using 1.2.26 indeed. Thanks for the reply.